# Why does comparing session variables directly not work?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a function `checkDate` that checks if the departure date is before the return date. Session variables `departDate` and `returnDate` have these dates stored.

```
var checkDates = function () {
  return departDate() < returnDate();
}

var departDate = function () {
  return Session.get("departDate");
}

var returnDate = function () {
  return Session.get("returnDate");
}
```

Will work and the handlebars `{{#if checkDates}}` will be fine.

However, if I do the following, it will not work for some reason:

```
var checkDates = function () {
  return (Session.get("departDate") < Session.get("returnDate"));
}
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Use the console to see what values are stored in those Session variables.

Comment: Why should that matter though? Because either way, I'm comparing the session variables, but it just depends on whether I get it through a function or not. Right?

Comment: I'm just saying... maybe you don't receive what you're expecting to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing the values to the Date constructor and co paint those values? I think you are basically comparing string lengths otherwise.